# Auto merge two form input values to one before patchEntity in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have table **Users** that has **telephone** field.

The problem is if I want to **seperate** user telephone number into 2 textboxes when showing user information and vice versa when User submits form, auto **merges** them into one value before **patchEntity()** and **save()** to database.

Can CakePHP make it nice and easy using CakePhp Form Helper?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Model.beforeMarshal` event to modify , restructure  request data before patching entitiy , The `beforMarshal` event is triggered just before the validation process. 
For example , to concatenate two form values to one you can do following

```
// In a table or behavior class
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, $data)
{
   $data['telephone'] = $data['telephone_1'].' '.  $data['telephone_2'];
}
```

Do not forget to add this statement `use Cake\Event\Event;` at the top of your table or behavior class. 
For more info about `Model.beforeMarshal` see http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#modifying-request-data-before-building-entities